# Get Pyspark Job Output on NodeJS

Tags: python, node.js, google-cloud-platform, pyspark

I successfully submitted a Pyspark job and I want to output the result of the job.

I got the result of the job from the following code:

```
const output = await storage
      .bucket(clusterResp.config.configBucket)
      .file(
        `google-cloud-dataproc-metainfo/${clusterResp.clusterUuid}/` +
          `jobs/${jobId}/driveroutput.000000000`
      )
      .download();
```

However, the result also includes all the logs from the job.

Is there any way to just get the output printed by my pyspark file without any logging info?

Answer (score 0):

According to the document [enter here](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/guides/driver-output) you can set --driver-log-levels to view driver/console output for the job.